Selecting a specific value in column 2, based on value in column 1, in a grid with XPATH
I am using selenium in Python to automate the tracking of attendance for events using a specific website for my organization. The list of attendees is built in a grid, with column 1 with the names of the attendees, and column 2 with the checkbox.
The idea for my Python code is to seek for a specific name in column 1, and then check the box in column 2.
The structure of the grid is the following:
<div id="grid" style="padding: 1em; display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(auto, 20em)); gap: 10px; align-items: center">
    <div style="grid-column: 1">
        "name1"                                        
    </div>
    <div style="width: 25px; grid-column: 2">
        <div class="cbx-container">
            <div class="cbx cbx-md cbx-active" tabindex="1000">
                <span class="cbx-icon"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="u1b7be9100c2-evforodn5xad-attended" class="check-all-item-1" name="attended-1" value="0" data-krajee-checkboxx="checkboxX_4d99482d" style="display: none;">
        </div>                                        
    </div>
    <div style="grid-column: 1">
        "name2"                                        
    </div>
    <div style="width: 25px; grid-column: 2">
        <div class="cbx-container">
            <div class="cbx cbx-md cbx-active" tabindex="1000">
                <span class="cbx-icon"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="u17528d00c2-evforodn5xad-attended" class="check-all-item-1" name="attended-1" value="0" data-krajee-checkboxx="checkboxX_4d99482d" style="display: none;">
        </div>                                        
    </div>                                                                                                          </div>

In the example above, I have 2 lines. In the first line, " name1" in column 1, and a checkbox in column 2. In the second line, " name2" in column 1, and a checkbox in column 2. The real dataset has more lines.
What would be the XPATH syntax to select the checkbox for "name2"?
Unfortunately, I was unable to get this done, as I am only starting with XPATH. So far, I was only able to select the names using the following:
"//div[contains(text(),'name2')]"


You were on the right track with your proposed XPath... you just needed one more step, following::, e.g.
//div[contains(text(),'name1')]//following::input

Since you are using python, you can assign the desired name to a variable, name, and then use that in your XPath, e.g.
name = "name1"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[contains(text(),'{name}')]//following::input")


Thank you so much! It did work, but with a small change: I used driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//div[contains(text(),'{name}')]//following::span") and it worked perfectly!! Thank you so much!!
